# Draftjs: Query if entity of type "x" exists in content

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm using draft-js in a chat client that I am building. I have created a custom entity that allows users to "@" mention other users. If a user is "@" mentioned, I want to send them a notification. Is there a way in draft-js to query the current editor state and ask if there are any entities matching a certain type? It would be nice if I could get data about that entity as well.

Answer (score 0):

please check the official [tweet](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/tree/master/examples/tweet) example. The `{props.children}` of your custom component will help you get the mentioned.